# How to get array values in string format

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am getting values from multiple checkboxes

```
<%for med_for in ['Self','Father', 'Mother', 'Spouse', 'Child_1', 'Child_2']%>
    <label style="display: inline-block;margin: 6px;"> <%=f.check_box :mediclaim_for,{ multiple: true }, :value=>med_for %>
    <%= med_for %> </label>
<%end%>
```

I have an array like:

```
[
  "0", "{:value=>\"Self\"}",
  "0", "{:value=>\"Father\"}", 
  "0", "{:value=>\"Mother\"}",
  "0", "{:value=>\"Spouse\"}",
  "0", "0"
]
```

In controller

```
  cand_dtl=params[:my_detail]
  medi_for_array = cand_dtl[:mediclaim_for].inspect //getting above array 
  abort medi_for_array.map{|s| s[/\{:value=>\"(.*)\"\}/, 1]}.compact
```

How can I get only values like:

```
"Self", "Father", "Mother", "Spouse"
```

Comment: What is the logic for having lower cased strings except for `"Father"`?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a =    [
  "0", "{:value=>\"Self\"}", "0", "{:value=>\"Father\"}",        
  "0", "{:value=>\"Mother\"}",       
  "0", "{:value=>\"Spouse\"}", "0", "0"       
]     
a.map{|s| s[/\{:value=>\"(.*)\"\}/, 1]}.compact
# => ["Self", "Father", "Mother", "Spouse"]
```

Comment: i am getting an error undefined method `map' for #<String:0x0055671fc5d560>

Comment: Did you see what I defined for `a`?

Comment: It does not use any Rails feature.

Comment: Sawa I have updated the question, could you please check

Comment: Sawa I have marked your answer as correct , it is working fine in ruby but working in ruby on rails, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.reject { |s| s == '0' }.map { |r| eval(r)[:value] }
```

Comment: @sawa, unless you don't know the source of the data being `evaled` it's quite natural reaction ^^

Comment: @fl00r My thought is that, only when you know (= the OP claimed) that the source of the data is from massive/unreliable users, then it's a natural reaction.

Comment: Seems like OP rarely consider to claim the source of the data. So I would go with the default assumption that data is unreliable.